# Java implementation of Crockford's Base32 encoding/decoding

Tags: java, encoding, base32

I'm looking for an implementation of [Crockford's Base32 encoding/decoding](http://www.crockford.com/wrmg/base32.html) in Java. Specifically, that means a Java library that I can use in my projects. Alternatively, some code example to do the encoding and decoding.

Comment: Not sure why this wouldn't be a real question that cannot reasonably be answered. spgennard managed to answer it nevertheless. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's pretty clear that an answer would be "an implementation of Crockford's Base32 encoding/decoding".  This isn't jeopardy, just because something isn't in the form of a question doesn't mean it's not clear what is being asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look @ https://bitbucket.org/yaler/yalercontrib/src/a8d40553a4d9/Java/DomainGen/DomainGen.java

Comment: Will try this, that looks exactly like what I was asking for. thanks!

Comment: Seems to be missing a decoder.

Comment: The link is dead as of today (2022-12-10).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/markov/5206312